# can't access database entries in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, dataset

I am using database variables in MATLAB.  When I try to access its entries, MATLAB doesn't recognize it.

```
mydataset(:,{AGE_ID});
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'. 

mydataset.AGE_ID;
No appropriate method, property, or field AGE_ID for class dataset.

mydataset(1:5,1:5);
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

However, `mydataset` is indeed seen as a dataset variable of sizes larger than `(5,5)` and calling `mydataset;` directly does print the whole set.

I can't understand what's going on.  I've already tried restarting MATLAB.

Thanks.

Comment: I realized this problem happens only in debugging mode.  I guess the real problem is a different one.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydataset(:,'AGE_ID')
```

Should give you all the rows for variable `AGE_ID`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did tried that, but didn't work either (when running in debug mode).  My workaround was creating a breakpoint before there was an error.

Comment: That's very weird. Maybe try raising the error with someone from MathWorks, they can look into it, maybe it's an error from their side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is subscripting at an error found while in debug mode.
A workaround is setting a break point before the error, where subscripting works normally.